# How to convert table rows to columns according the relation of data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to change my row data as column according their id as the table below.
There i have to show 5 words in a row of same id and if there have less then 5 words for an id the rest column will be fill by '--' sign. I am using mysql here and i need a dynamic way to do this for any quantity of data.

My Table:

```
wordID   Word     Per     Sequence
  1      Kelly    68          1
  1      John     26          2
  2      Nisum    5.29        1
  2      Bily     14.1        2
  2      George   10          3
  2      Rihana   22          4
  3      August   72          1
  3      Rush     22          2
  3      Routh    95          3
```

Desired Table:

```
wordID   word    Per   word    Per    word    Per   word    Per   word   Per    
  1      Kelly   68    John    26      --     --     --     --    --    --
  2      Nisum   5.29  Bily    14.1   George  10    Rihana  22    --    --
  3      August  72    Rush    22     Routh   95     --     --    --    --
```

Comment: I've rolled back to text version of your data. Please do not post images containing data.

Answer (score 1):

Following query will give you expected results :

```
SELECT wordID,  

    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='1' THEN Word ELSE NULL END),'--') AS Word, 
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='1' THEN Per ELSE NULL END),'--') AS  Per,

    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='2' THEN Word ELSE NULL END),'--') AS Word, 
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='2' THEN Per ELSE NULL END),'--') AS  Per,

    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='3' THEN Word ELSE NULL END),'--') AS Word, 
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='3' THEN Per ELSE NULL END),'--') AS  Per,

    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='4' THEN Word ELSE NULL END),'--') AS Word, 
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='4' THEN Per ELSE NULL END),'--') AS  Per,

    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='5' THEN Word ELSE NULL END),'--') AS Word, 
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence='5' THEN Per ELSE NULL END),'--') AS  Per

FROM tableName 

GROUP BY wordID
```

Note* : This will be useful only when you are limiting maximum number of words allowed for given wordID. i.e In your case which is 5.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It is very helpful for me. But i need a dynamic way for any quantity of data. I should mention that but it was a mistake. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for this types of problems:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EElQ.png)